# Blockquote Not working in CKEditor (Django)

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm working on a project and I'm using CKEditor. After struggles, most features work but blockquote is not working. I work on the editor itself but when I display on template it's not.
see screen shorts

[image: on ckeditor]

on templates after printing the field its gone

[image: on templates]

Here is how I added it
[image]

Comment: Did you check the field's content ? Most probably, the markup is correctly generated (by ckedit) and stored in the db and the only issue is with your css that don't render the blockquotes correctly. Less probably but still possible, the markup is just not correctly stored in your db. In both cases, only you can check this.